# Connecting to a Mariadb container through another unrelated container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, mariadb

I have two container stacks/projects :

- First is a full PHP/Nginx/Mariadb app stack working plainly on itself. It is in its own docker-compose file.
- Second is a PHP/Nginx app without its own DB in a separate docker-composer file. I want it to plug on first stack's DB container.

I started the 2 stacks, they run fine on their own, but I can't reach the DB.

I assume it's because a container runs in a virtual LAN, and I need to create a VLAN between the 2 containers.
Also I must add that I can't edit the first project in any way, i can only edit my local project (the second one).

Regards,

Comment: Using a separate database per project is a typical microservice setup; why not add a separate database to the second Compose setup?

Comment: Because the idea for the second project is to access the data of the very same DB as first project. Not to duplicate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I suggest instead of installing the Db on the first container and then trying to connect your second project to it, install it in another container.

That makes three different containers. Two for your projects, and a third one just for your MariaDb.

Now for connecting to this Db:
Make a network in Docker, and add these three containers to it.
To do so run this command:

```
Create docker network <'network name'>
```

In your docker-compose files, add this at the end of the service you created:

```
networks:
  - <'network name'>
```

and at the end of the file, add this:

```
networks:
  <'network name'>:
    external: true
```

Comment: The DB is on a separate container in first project, if I understand Docker correctly. The first project is based on 3 containers : Nginx, php code and MariaDB. The second project is another Nginx and phpcode.
I assume the real issue is, like you said in a second time, a network issue.

Comment: Well you are confusing containers and images together. In your first container, you have 3 images. I would do this if I were you, your dockerizing will be so much simpler. Just install PHP on two containers. Install Mariadb on a third container. Follow the steps from above to connect your containers together. And instead of using Nginx in each container, simply install it on your machine. and in your containers, forward the ports that your project is running on(If its a backend project). And then in your Nginx files, tell it to listen to those ports.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. I will try that.